# Error: type 'vector<int>' does not provide a call operator

Tags: c++, oop

I was solving a question on [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-hashmap/), where I had to initialize a vector with all elements set to -1. I declared the vector outside the class, and tried inserting value in the constructor function, Here is my code:

> ```
> class MyHashMap {
>
> private: 
>     vector<int>key;
>     
> public:
>     MyHashMap() {
>         key(1e6+1, -1);
>     }
>     
>     void put(int x, int y) {
>         key[x]=y;
>     }
>     
>     int get(int x) {
>         return key[x];
>     }
>     
>     void remove(int x) {
>         key[x]=-1;
>     }
> };
> ```

I was facing this error in the constructor function.

> error: type 'vector' does not provide a call operator
> key(1e6+1, -1);

However, if in the constructor function I write a code like:-

> MyHashMap(): key(1e6+1, -1) {}

It was working fine then. Can someone explain me the error reason and how did it get fix.

Comment: One is an initialiser and the other is just calling the variable. `: key(1e6+1,-1)` is somewhat equivalent to `std::vector<int> key{1e6+1,-1};` while `key(1e6 + 1, -1)` will be equivalent to `key(1e6 + 1, -1)`

Comment: The first is the same situation as `vector<int>key; key(1e6+1, -1);` which you most likely wouldn't expect to work. (If you don't have one, get yourself a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).)

Comment: @whynesspower Same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729916/is-constructor-delegation-the-same-as-calling-the-constructor).